# Limiting image rows by 5 but an unknown number of section entries

Tags: entries

I'm trying to limit the total number of images shown to 5. The below clearly isn't correct but gives a rough idea of what i want to do.

One entry could contain 1 image and the next entry 3 images. So i can't set a limit on the craft.entries tag because of the unknown number of images in an entry. It's on the images for loop i want to limit to 5.

```
{% for images in craft.entries.section('pages').type('events').order('eventDate desc').eventDate('<=' ~ now).search('gallery:*') %}
    {% for image in images.gallery.limit(5) %}
        <li><a href="{{image.getUrl}}"><img src="{{image.getUrl('smallImage')}}" alt="{{image.title}}" class="image-link" /></a></li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a counter and count the images actually displayed in your nested for loops. Then add a conditional to the loops to stop the iteration at your set limit.

With that many parameters set on your `craft.entries`
[ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) I would really recommend to use the [object syntax](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) to set them. And instead of using the `search` parameter to check if there's images set to your entries, you would better use `relatedTo` and filter by entries with relations to an image model.

```
{% set assets = craft.assets.limit(null) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'pages',
    type: 'events',
    eventDate: '<= ' ~ now,
    relatedTo: assets,
    order: 'eventDate desc',
}) %}

<ul>
    {% set count = 0 %}
    {% for entry in entries if count < 5 %}
        {% for image in entry.gallery if count < 5 %}
            <li><img src="{{ image.getUrl('smallImage') }}"></li>
            {% set count = count + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, why would it be beneficial to use the object syntax? And why a relatedto?

Comment: Don't you think the object syntax is more readable with that many parameters? And `relatedTo` because that's what as assets field does under the hood, it relates assets to your entry. I wouldn't use search unless it's absolutely necessary, because it relies on a search index file that might be not up-to-date.

Comment: Oh yes it's certainly more readable i thought there might be a performance issue. Thanks for your help. Appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can also just use  `loop.index` which is auto-incremented.

Comment: @Douglas wouldn't the loop var be reset for each outer loop iteration?

Comment: @carlcs Just tested. You're right (as usual) — doesn't like `loop.index` in the conditional (throws error).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
{% for images in craft.entries.section('pages').type('events').order('eventDate desc').eventDate('<=' ~ now).search('gallery:*') %}

    {% set image_set = images.gallery %}
    {% for i in 0..4 %}
        {% if image_set[i] is defined %}
            <li><a href="{{image_set[i].getUrl}}"><img src="{{image_set[i].getUrl('smallImage')}}" alt="{{image_set[i].title}}" class="image-link" /></a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```